# Communication between iOS's native app and webpage's javascript

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a webpage loaded in a UIWebView, and a javascript function of the page needs to data  from native iOs app, a NSString. How can a Js function access the data in native app?

Thanks,

lvreiny

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can execute JavaScript in your UIWebView from Obj-C. Simply call `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJavaScript"];`.

I could imagine a setup like this:

**Webpage**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function callmeFromObjC(para1) {
             // do something
             alert(para1);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *myParameter = @"myParameter";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"callmeFromObjC('%@')", myParameter]];
```

Comment: thanks, It works. is there a way which allows to call iOS's function from javascript?

Comment: Did you even read my answer? I know it doesn't have sample code, but it has the answer to the question in your comment.

Comment: Implement a custom URL scheme like Johan Kool suggested and then call your url like this from JS "myapp://parameter1/parameter2/parameter3" to make this work you also need to implement the method "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url" in your app delegate. Here's a complete tutorial about just that: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: Björn is correct, except that you don't necessarily need to overwrite `-application:handleOpenURL:`. Usually it's easier to do this in `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Answer (score 7):

With WebViewJavaScriptBridge you can achieve two way communication between javaScript and iOS.

Check this link below for WebViewJavaScriptBridge .

I used this bridge for one of my application for communication between iOS and JS and also vice versa.

https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge.

Answer (score 4):

I created an iOS/JS library to help make this easier -- that is, communication in both directions using similar methods. You can check it out here: https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs

Answer (score 1):

Let the javascript load a custom URL, which your app intercepts. It than can parse it, prepare the data and pass it on to your webpage via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.

Comment: hi, here is how i implemented it:

Comment: i have a function jsfunc(){ location.href =" a custom url" }, I use webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType to handle the url and call a native function.The problem is that the native function returns a string,and jsfunc() should return that string. How to do it? I made a workaround by calling another js function from native code using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and pass the returnstring to it, but it would be better if jsfunc() can return it directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<script src=\"filename.js\"></script>" 
      baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function(parameter)"];
```

Give feedback to iOS

```
window.location = customprefix://function/parameter=value

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"customprefix"]) {
        // handle function name and paramters
    }
}
```

I also wrote a guide on how to call and handle different javascript functions from within iOS.
http://www.dplusmpage.com/2012/07/20/execute-javascript-on-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for this is available here,you can check it....very usefull

http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/framework-for-interacting-with-embedded-webview-in-ios-application/